# Como redondear un valor decimal y mostrar 0.50 en vez de 0.5 en php

Tags: php, symfony2, twig

Deseo redondear un valor en mi proyecto php de manera tal que en ves de mostrarme por ejemplo 12.5 me muestre el cero del 50 (12.50)

Comment: como obtienes ese valor? en que formato te llega? por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Estoy trabajando con symfony....y mando el  array asociativo para mi vista twig con el valor obtenido.....luego uso twig para rendondear....

Comment: Si pudiera redondearlo desde el mismo controlador o en la vista....seria genial...pero siempre me elimina el cero de la derecha del numero.

Comment: tal vez y solo tal vez `number_format(valor, decimales)` te sirva busca al respecto

Comment: Ok..tratare de subir algo de codigo..disculpenme

Comment: Tu pregunta queda mucho más precisa si la editas y especificas que usas symfony y Twig como sistema de plantillas ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) (que por lo que veo es el sistema de plantillas que estás usando) también tienes una llamada a [number_format](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html) que funciona de manera muy similar:

```
{{ tu_numero | number_format(2, ',', '.') }}
```

Los parámetros son los siguientes:

- El primero para indicar el **número de decimales**, en éste ejemplo 2.
- El segundo para indicar el carácter a usar como **separador decimal**, en este ejemplo una coma.
- El tercer valor para indicar el carácter a usar como **separador de mile**s en este caso un punto.

Comment: Gracias mi hermanito....me sirvió....un millón de gracias.

Comment: De nada, **Twig** es un sistema de plantillas muy sencillo pero muy potente. Son poco los `helpers` y `funciones` que trae por defecto, pero si las dominas le vas a sacar mucho rendimiento ;-)

Comment: yo estaba usando el filtro  round()...pero no me habia percatado del filtro number_format().....y es verdad twig es muy potente. saludos reiterados.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi
javascript:

```
var num=12.5;
num.toFixed(2);
```

php:

```
$num=12.5; 
money_format('%i', $number);
```

Comment: Este también lo probé y pincha genial. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En php puedes usar `string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = ".")`

Comment: A ver...eso lo hago desde el controlador para formatear el dato??

Comment: Me demoré en aplicarlo pero también sirve...saludos brother.